# Make sure partitioning is working

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

I created a partition for a table. There is a column "archived" (`tinyint`). 0 goes to PRIMARY data file, 1 to ARCHIVED data file.

```
ALTER DATABASE MYDB ADD FILEGROUP [ARCHIVED];

ALTER DATABASE MYDB ADD FILE (NAME = N'ARCHIVED', FILENAME
  = N'D:\...\MYDB_ARCHIVED.mdf' ...) TO
  FILEGROUP [ARCHIVED];

CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION FNArchived (tinyint) AS
RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES (0);

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME SCArchived
    AS PARTITION FNArchived
    TO ([PRIMARY],[ARCHIVED]);
GO
```

The I dropped the primary key and added this :

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT PK_mytable PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED  (uid) ON [PRIMARY]; 
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_mytable_archived ON mytable (archived) ON SCArchived(archived);
```

All seems fine there is no error.

But how can I make sure that data is written to the right data file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can monitor the number of rows as you perform inserts. This is the script I use, [borrowed from Dejan Sarka](http://blogs.solidq.com/dsarka/Post.aspx?ID=43):

```
;WITH prc([Partition], [Rows]) 
AS
(
  SELECT $PARTITION.PartitionFunctionName(PartitioningColumn), COUNT(*)
     FROM dbo.TableName
     GROUP BY $PARTITION.PartitionFunctionName(PartitioningColumn)
),
pds([Partition], [FileGroup])
AS
(
   SELECT dds.destination_id,
          ds.name
     FROM sys.destination_data_spaces AS dds
     INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS i
       ON dds.partition_scheme_id = i.data_space_id
     INNER JOIN sys.data_spaces AS ds
       ON dds.data_space_id = ds.data_space_id
     INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o
       ON i.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
     INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
       ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
     WHERE o.name = N'TableName'
       AND s.name = N'dbo'
       AND i.index_id < 2
)
SELECT pds.[FileGroup], [Rows] = COALESCE(SUM(prc.[Rows]),0)
  FROM pds
  LEFT OUTER JOIN prc
  ON prc.[Partition] = pds.[Partition]
  GROUP BY pds.[FileGroup];
```

I haven't tested thoroughly, but I think this could be simplified without having to use the `$PARTITION` function or touch the base table at all:

```
SELECT ds.name, [rows] = SUM(p.[rows])
  FROM sys.destination_data_spaces dds
  INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS i
    ON dds.partition_scheme_id = i.data_space_id
  INNER JOIN sys.data_spaces AS ds
    ON dds.data_space_id = ds.data_space_id
  INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o
    ON i.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
    ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
  INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p
    ON o.[object_id] = p.[object_id]
    AND i.index_id = p.index_id
    AND dds.destination_id = p.partition_number
  WHERE o.name = @TableName
    AND s.name = N'dbo'
    AND i.index_id < 2
    AND p.index_id < 2
  GROUP BY ds.name;
```

Comment: on msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms188730.aspx I found this query : SELECT * FROM sys.partitions AS p
JOIN sys.tables AS t
    ON  p.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE p.partition_id IS NOT NULL
    AND t.name = 'PartitionTable';   
Which return the same thing in a less human readable format

Comment: Interesting, I was part-way through converting the script to my rig and ran it, but it completes without error even when "PartitionFunctionName" does not exist.  Steps to reproduce: 1) replace tableName with real table, 2) replace PartitioningColumn with real column, 3) run script.  Outcome: script completes with no output and no error.  Expected outcome: Error on PartitionFunctionName does not exist.  Funky feature of CTE with $partition.  Worth a connect item @AaronBertrand?

Comment: Connect item up.  Pretty minor but worth a look: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/993662/odd-behaviour-with-partition-function-and-common-table-expression-cte

Answer (score 1):

In order to validate your partitioning scheme, you can use the `$PARTITION` system function, detailed on MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188071.aspx

> Returns the partition number into which a set of partitioning column values would be mapped for any specified partition function

So for your example, you could run:

```
SELECT $PARTITION.FNArchived (1);
```

or

```
SELECT $PARTITION.FNArchived (0);
```

To determine which partition each value will be stored in.

Comment: This is nice to test partionning function thanks !